Is there a reliable way or heuristic to determine if a COBOL section does / does not fall through when constructing a control flowgraph?
I'm constructing a control flowgraph for some COBOL code as an exercise.
For this question, I consider the following code:
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.PROGRAM-ID. IRREDUCIBLE-TEST.
 AUTHOR.        MOJO.
 ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
 DATA DIVISION.
 WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  TESTING    PIC 9(8) VALUE 100.
 PROCEDURE DIVISION.
 ROOT SECTION.
   PERFORM MAIN-SECTION-01.
   STOP RUN.
 MAIN-SECTION-01 SECTION.
   MAIN-SECTION-01-A.
      IF  TESTING = 5
         GO  TO  MAIN-SECTION-01-Z.
      PERFORM  SUBROUTINE-1.
   MAIN-SECTION-01-Z.
      EXIT.
 SUBROUTINE-1 SECTION.
   SUBROUTINE-1-A.
      EXIT.

It is clear from visual inspection that control flow does not fall through after MAIN-SECTION-01 is executed (i.e., SUBROUTINE-1 is not executed following MAIN-SECTION-01's exit), because MAIN-SECTION-01 is called through a PERFORM.
However, indiscriminately connecting sections which are sequential from a syntactic perspective (like MAIN-SECTION-01 to SUBROUTINE-1) results in an irreducible flowgraph (using T1-T2 transforms), like so:
Irreducible flowgraph resulting for indiscriminate linking of serial sections
My question is: is there a reasonable heuristic or graph-theoretic basis for determining unambiguously if a section does not fall through to the next section? I know that there will always be situations where there is not a clear YES/NO answer because of decisions based on computed conditions, but in cases where this is no ambiguity (like in the program above), what would be a reasonable approach?
I'd very much appreciate any pointers to any relevant techniques that I can go off and explore by myself.
One way I've circumvented this problem is to let the developer explicitly specify which sections/paragraphs do not have incoming fallthrough connections. This works, but I'd be happier automating (some) of that decision-making.

"it is clear from visual inspection" = the necessary rules are already in your mind, you "just" have to codify them.

It's been decades since I'd seen SECTIONS in a COBOL program.  Any GO TO statements in the code will make it harder to determine control flow, especially if they go to a different SECTION.

If you "fall into" a SECTION or "GO TO" into a section then the code will fall through to the next paragraph or section.
Basically unless you "PERFORM" a section the implicit exit does not take place and control falls to the next paragraph.

Right, and I could use the "PERFORM means no fallthrough" heuristic, but a section could be both PERFORMed (from some section) and entered via normal fallthrough from the preceding section. I am asking whether there is a definitive way to say "this section is NEVER executed by a fallthrough" short of tracing through all possible condition states of the program.

Like what James Anderson said, there is no heuristic other than analysing the code.
Our company has policies: We only perform paragraphs, we do not allow GO TO (except to the paragraph that the GO TO is part of).  So, if a programmer followed our policies then you know that only the beginning section falls through (and any ENTRY points).  But that only helps if the programmer follows procedure properly. <shrug>
